# How to reset EKAuthorizationStatusRestricted in iOS Calendar?

Tags: ios, calendar, authorization, status

In my app, I am trying to add entries in the user's Calendar. To reflect the authorization status in my UI, I use `authorizationStatusForEntityType` to determine whether the user has already given or denied permission. The first time, i.e. before the app has asked permission, the status is `EKAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined`. After is has displayed the question, I cannot find a way to put the status back to `EKAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined` in order for me to continue testing my app. Even removing and re-installing my app it does not help. I can go to Settings, General, Reset, Reset Location & Privacy, but that erases **all** my privacy settings, not just the one for my app.

So the question is: is there any way to reset the authorization for my app?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to reset the authorization status except the way you already described (i.e. Settings -> reset all).

Comment: Thanks. Not the answer I was hoping to get, but I guess there is indeed no other way...